# is option+shift highlighting shortcut missing in atom.io?

Tags: github, text-editor, atom-editor

In Sublime Text, I regularly use two shortcuts to highlight code.

To highlight from my cursor, all the way to the top or bottom of the file, I use command+shift+arrow(up||down).

To highlight from my cursor, up/down line by line, I use option+shift+arrow(up||down).

Both of the shortcuts have different functionality when you use the left & right arrows, and in that use case they work just fine in atom.io.

I can't seem to get option+shift to work in conjunction with (up/down) arrows in atom.io.

Can someone explain why and provide a remedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can select lines from my cursor up and down by using `Shift+Up` or `Shift+Down`- is that what you're looking for?

What happens if you open the *Key Binding Resolver* (`Cmd+.`) and then do `Shift+Up` or `Alt+Shift+Up`? Atom should show you the resolved key bindings.

If `Shift+Up` is what you're looking for, you can easily remap that to `Alt+Shift+Up`.

Comment: Shift + Up is exactly what I am talking about. For some reason I was using option+shift+up -- will be dropping the option key now. Thanks.